# "Derivation" matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, reference-request

I am working on a problem, where the following operation on matrices pops up:

Let $A$ be a matrix with non-negative integer entries and let $i$ be a row index.
In the matrix $\partial_i A$ all rows with indices $\neq i$ are the same as in $A$. In the $i$-th row the non-zero entries are reduced by $1$ and the zero entries stay the same.

Does this construction have a name? Was it studied somewhere in mathematics?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I very much doubt this has been named or studied. You can invent a name ("derivation" seems wrong to me).  If you have questions about its properties you can ask them here.

Comment: Could you give the context motivating the introduction of such an operation (Instead of *derivation*, this operation is the application of the **sign** function to the $i$th row because all entries are $\ge 0$).

Comment: @Jean Marie: Note that the $i$-th column's non-zero entries are reduced by one and not set equal to one.

Comment: Ahhh, I had understood the "reduced by one" as "reduced to one"...